# Ubuntu 9.10 - getlibs - Libraries Not Found?

Tags: ubuntu, android, apt

I'm using the getlibs package to obtain Android 32 bit dependencies for the aapt tool. However, when this is run, I get the following- Note the **Not Found** on the ubuntu16 libraries. I checked the server and sure enough, they're not there. However ubuntu15 and ubuntu17 are. What gives?

I even changed the http to ftp and reviewed the site here: ftp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/ and the ubuntu16 seems to be gone.

Even if I perform an apt-get such as:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I still see that the sources cannot be found. Any ideas? If they are moved to the *17 versions. How do I change from 16 to 17 locally?

```
root@myserver:/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-8/tools# getlibs aapt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc-bin libc6 libc6-i386 libv4l-0
Suggested packages:
  lib32asound2-plugins glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ia32-libs lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386 libv4l-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc6
2 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 8661kB/39.1MB of archives.
After this operation, 145MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main libc-bin 2.10.1-0ubuntu16
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main libc6 2.10.1-0ubuntu16
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main libc6-i386 2.10.1-0ubuntu16
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc-bin_2.10.1-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.10.1-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-i386_2.10.1-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.46 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
This application isn't missing any dependencies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to upgrade the system. I did so with the following:

```
apt-get update
```

Then I ran:

```
getlibs aapt
```

... and then all dependencies were downloaded.